# C# - ListView Null exception

Tags: c#, listview, null, scroll

I am struggling with ListViews for a while...I am writing a program which I cant copy in here (it has 637 lines long)...basically I am trying to delete the selected lines of a ListView...BUT if the ListView is big enough to show a scrolling bar it chashes the program saying that an "object reference was not set for an instance of an object", it actually don't completly crashes, but it shows an ugly JIT debugging window.
I know that the problem is with the size of the ListView, because if I just try to delete any item of the ListView with an active scrolling bar, I get the crash, BUT if I just resize the window to be big enough to disable the scrolling bar (i.e. big enough so everything will fit and a scroll bar wont be necessary thus the system will not make one), everything works just fine!
I am suspecting that maybe it is some internal bug of the .NET plataform....any ideas?

(I already tried all kinds of codes for deleting selected items, every single one of them had this same error, but I made it work by copying all the ListView to an Array, and deleting the selected items in the array, and then copying them back to a clean ListView....weird, messy, ugly, I know, but it was the only code that worked...but now I am getting this same bug BUT only after installing the program, this is not happening when I run the program in Visual Studio!)

EDIT:
the delete code is (the commented part are all the codes I previously tried and failed in the same bug....this one only crashes when istalled, not in Visual Studio 2010...Framework is .NET 4.0):

```
private void limparLinhasSelecionadas() 
        {
            if (listView1.Items.Count > 0 && limpando == false)
            {
                limpando = true;
                int i = 0; 

                //for (i = listView1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
                //{
                    //if (listView1.Items[i].Selected == true)
                    //{
                    //    listView1.Items[i].Remove();                       
                    //}

                //}              
                //////for (i = listView1.SelectedIndices.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                //////{
                //////    listView1.Items[listView1.SelectedIndices[i]].Remove();
                //////}
                //foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.SelectedItems)
                //{
                //    listView1.Items.Remove(item);
                //}

                ArrayList itens = new ArrayList();

                foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
                {
                    itens.Add(item);
                }

                foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.SelectedItems)
                {
                    itens.Remove(item);                    
                }

                listView1.Items.Clear();

                foreach (ListViewItem item in itens)
                {
                    listView1.Items.Add((ListViewItem)item.Clone());
                }

                //for (i = 0; i < itens.Count; i ++)
                //{                    
                //    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem((itens[i] as ListViewItem).Text);

                //    for (j = 1; j < (itens[i] as ListViewItem).SubItems.Count; j++)
                //    {
                //        item.SubItems.Add((itens[i] as ListViewItem).SubItems[j].Text);                     
                //    }
                //    listView1.Items.Add(item);
                //}

                for (i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    listView1.Items[i].Text = "Passe " + (i + 1).ToString();
                }

                ////ListView listView = new ListView();

                ////int j = 0;

                ////for (i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
                ////{
                ////    //listView.Items.Add(listView1.Items[i]);
                ////    for (j = 0; j < listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Count; j++)
                ////    {
                ////        listView.Items[i].SubItems.Add(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[j].Text);
                ////    }
                ////}

                ////listView1.Items.Clear();

                ////for (i = 0; i < listView.Items.Count; i++)
                ////{
                ////    listView1.Items.Add(listView.Items[i].Clone() as ListViewItem);
                ////}

                //foreach (ListViewItem item in listViewCollection)
                //{
                //    listView1.Items.Add(item.Clone() as ListViewItem);
                //}

                SetWindowTheme(listView1.Handle, "Explorer", null);
                limpando = false;
            }

           // SetWindowTheme(listView1.Handle, "Explorer", null);
        }
```

Comment: Show the code that you delete your selected items

Comment: Can you please edit your code to contain the relevant parts and post it?  Yourpostishardtoread.

Comment: Consider to apply Paging in your listview, it will resolve all your problems

Comment: How do I do Paging? Can you point a link with more information?

Comment: Guys I am pretty sure there is no coding bug...I have removed line by line until the bug disapeared...basicaly, removing `listView1.Clear();` made the bug disapear...so to fix it, I just replaced the `listView1.Clear();` to a method that creates a new empty listView from scratch....its waste of memmory, but its working....

Comment: [`ListView.Clear()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.clear.aspx) is different to `ListView.Items.Clear()` in that it also removes the columns.

Comment: That's why I am using `ListView.Items.Clear()` so only the items will be cleared...so why is it a problem?

Comment: @UweKeim I wrote it wrong...I was using all the time `ListView.Items.Clear()` sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to delete the selected items from a listview, this code will work.

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.SelectedItems)
{
    listView1.Items.Remove(item);
}
```

Comment: If you look at my code and notes, I tried that code already...its commented because it didn't work...when the ListView grows and a scrollbar appears, when I delete some item the program crashes....that's an old problem I had, at that time, there was a "ghost" item, in a position greater than the collection of items itself, and when the code tryied to look at it, it crashed. That's why I placed all the commented code, they are all "not worked" code.
To get around this problem, I copied the ListView to an Array and deleted from the Array and then I copied it back...as I already explained before.

Comment: I made a test project and tested it, it works. I added 100 items and remove from anywhere within that list, no problem. I suspect that your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: do you have any other references to the items in the list ?

Comment: no..no other references... I will try to replicate this behaviour a simpler code next week and I will post it in here